# RSA private key in PEM Format

Tags: java, rsa

My generated RSA keys are invalid in external systems.

I've generated RSA Keys using Java.

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = null;
try {
generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
generator.initialize(2048);
KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();


StringBuilder sbPrivate = new StringBuilder();
sbPrivate.append("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
sbPrivate.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
sbPrivate.append("\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");

StringBuilder sbPublic = new StringBuilder();
sbPublic.append("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
sbPublic.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
sbPublic.append("\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
```

In result I've got:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
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
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArbp3VERWhYaIj5mjW3x1KFkC3KIcnZcJeq4i7uuEC/zspfFeIKhk9pfzogtsVDKz/EPoilmwWg0q93Zl0uTQYr+UADyUdxrRhPID+c0aSEnlfLjzL1NgKOT2hLDms2AiE1QwI/m/pA0NuQKtOdgkyMMoQJ3NDj7AMkjWKTYGSqRy9HcmNLxxPYW8DeqnO+sN0JQvjqNLMD6qCDt05NVZ7IFd/uXOb0icB2EyxDX0i/LnlcZ+/UUWDJCBchXF8QOy6iKeQcq+N9H/WZvo00dsi0j53TLHnrQwrBJqLs10fKSCzMUxXZoYrL+mDTxhOUgYdAlHuLYYKk9m6hBG8FLHDQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But when I'm trying to use this keys here
https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample/sample-rsasign.html
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption
These keys are invalid.

Where could be a problem?

Comment: The Java code exports the private key in PKCS#8 format and the public key in X.509/SPKI format and neither of them in PKCS#1 format. The headers/footers you use belong to PKCS#1 format. The equivalents for PKCS#8 are: BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY and for X.509/SPKI: BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY.

Comment: The jsrsasign site expects a key in PKCS#1 format, which is the reason for the failure. The devglan site expects PKCS#8 and X.509/SPKI format, which is why it should work. It may not work for you because of an input issue. The keys must be input without header/footer (neither with the right ones and anyway not with the wrong ones).

Comment: For completeness, to actually be PEM format the base64 must be broken into multiple lines; the spec (1421 or 7468) is at 64 characters. Some reader programs require this, some do not. In Java if you use `Base64.getMimeEncoder()` it breaks at 76 characters, which is often (but not always) close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe keys are not being written to standard PEM formats: PKCS8 & X.509 respectively.

The following works but the keys need to be tested on https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp. This shows the PEMs are good.
However, neither of the sites you suggested can process them.

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;

import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPKCS8Generator;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;

public class Whatever {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048); 
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try (JcaPEMWriter w = new JcaPEMWriter(writer)) {
            w.writeObject(new JcaPKCS8Generator(kp.getPrivate(), null));
        }
        
        PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
        pemWriter.writeObject(new PemObject("PUBLIC KEY", kp.getPublic().getEncoded()));
        pemWriter.flush();
        pemWriter.close();

        System.out.println (writer.toString());

    }
```

Output:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlxytO6GqsfH52K91G31E
uh0V0BUb0NCfKqs4KvlB+GarYMVeOHIkjsMy+uRNmma4sV8QfrOym28NakdKFDb2
svEITJZsFGcF4wmW3jW0CPC16F0lNZfccdhmewUt/4bhRh0shs460mCXSXGSjmIo
9umgjyMe1WBHiFJjwG5AgNVVVIWjonPNWkAHYaqyo6qQXGE8GFuGBds3Mg8fGC60
SyW4xczPeHoPaBK6iLKbcmfN3WqDcrVU24o8w6FwJpB68efDX2Z7idCXx1ChmYjJ
benwQKg0d/g5bOoXpiQPlcQjtnSgQ6dr0hnyA3NZq9ZEKMxStyahSDXFiOd+75z1
lQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Results from 8gwifi.org
Private key:

```
 Private Key algo RSA
 Private Format  PKCS#8
 ASN1 Dump
RSA Private CRT Key [f9:3d:bb:ce:14:eb:b6:f4:68:c0:69:54:a8:47:da:56:78:6d:d2:ad]
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001
```

Public key:

```
Algo RSA
Format X.509
 ASN1 Dump
RSA Public Key [a6:cc:21:c6:b2:98:92:7a:96:d6:5b:ac:38:32:0c:dc:a3:1c:42:e5]
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001
```

There is a dependency on Bouncy Castle as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.56</version>
</dependency>
```